# Removing prefix from minor-mode keymap

Tags: keymap, prefix-keys

Have been constructing a minor mode, taking code for the `keymap` from `outline.el`.  I want to remove the use of a prefix key but I am unsure by what thing `(key-description outline-minor-mode-prefix)` should be replaced by.

```lisp
    (defvar tika-prefix-map
      (let ( (pfmap (make-sparse-keymap)) )
        (define-key pfmap "H-t" 'outline-hide-body)
        (define-key pfmap "H-a" 'outline-show-all)
        (define-key pfmap "H-e" 'outline-show-entry)
        pfmap))

    (define-minor-mode tika-minor-mode
      "Enhances visibility of heading levels and text emphasis."
      :init-value nil
      :lighter " Tika"
      :keymap (define-keymap
                :parent outline-minor-mode-cycle-map
                "<menu-bar>" tika-menubar-kmap
                (key-description outline-minor-mode-prefix) tika-prefix-map)  
    
       (if tika-minor-mode
             (do-this)
          (do-that)))
```

But after changing the minor-mode `define-key` to be
the following, the minor-mode menu disappears.

```lisp
    (define-minor-mode tika-minor-mode
      :init-value nil
      :lighter " Tika"
      :keymap (define-keymap
                :suppress "<menu-bar>"
                :name tika-menubar-kmap
                :keymap tika-prefix-map)
```

Comment: `C-h f define-keymap` to understand what the pieces are. Then read `Outline minor mode` in the Emacs manual to understand what the prefix does. It seems to me that that is something you don't need, so try leaving out the whole last line (do you have a `tika-prefix-map` at all? That looks to be outline-mode specific) - but you'll still need the closing paren.

Comment: I have done all that you have instructed,  I understand what the prefix does but I want to use different key bindings for the outline commands that do not use any prefix (simply `H-this`, `H-that`).

Comment: Yes I have introduced `tika-prefix-map`.  Which in shown by the `defvar` above,.

Comment: You introduced it because you need it or because `outline-minor-mode` did that?

Comment: If I remove it, I do not get the menu.  I also removed `:parent`.